# Ionic 4 Angular navigate as the set root and as the back button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

It's already decided. Everyone says not to use NavController in Ionic 4 and instead we use Angular's router. I'm not using lazy loading feature and I simply use routes like this :

```
{ path: '', component: WalkthroughComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

now to redirect I write `this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");`.

Question is: sometimes I want to navigate user such as they shouldn't have back button at the left-top side of the screen, but sometimes such as he should have a back button to go to. When using NavController, it was easy - `functions ( setRoot, push, pop).` What do I do to have same idea, but using Angular's router?

Comment: In that case use angular router and you manually show the back button at the top or else using NavController is good for easily navigating through pages in mobile.

Answer (score 2):

The methods like navigateRoot, navigateBack and navigateForward are here in place of setRoot, pop, push.

Suppose if you want to make your page set to the root page in Ionic 4 you should use **navigateRoot** instead of **setRoot**

```
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/pageName');
```

**goForward() -> navigateForward()**

**goBack() -> navigateBack()**

**goRoot() -> navigateRoot()**